# Google Maps: redefine center point, fit bounds to specific area

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here's a real challenge I'm running into using the Google Maps API. I've got an app that is full-screen, there's a Google map that fills the entire background. Some of the UI chrome for this app covers parts of the maps, so, in effect, the entire map is not always visible.

Instead, we have a "primary" visible area, and a "partially" visible area, like so:

[image: map example]

Here are my questions:

Normally if you want to center something in the view you call `map.setCenter(latLng)` This puts the given latLng in the exact center of the map canvas. However, in my case, I'd like to put the given latLng not in the exact center of the canvas, but in the center of the fully visible portion of the canvas.

I haven't been able to find any documentation of a way to set a geographic point to anything other than the exact center of the canvas. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Likewise, if you want to zoom the map so it fits a number of points, you can pass all of these latLngs to a bounds object, on each one calling `bounds.extend(latLng)`, and then `map.fitBounds(bounds)`.

However, this will fit the map so that the points are displayed within the entire map canvas. Is it possible to make them fit to a specific portion of the canvas instead?

Thanks for any insight here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After creating the map use the panBy-method of the map to pan the map by the given pixels.

```
map.panBy(rightPadding/2,-topPadding/2);
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/JsBEx/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/JsBEx/)

Comment: Ok, this is a great idea for centering points. Do you have any thoughts on how to ensure all points in a bounds are fit within the visible area and not the total area?

Comment: After working on this at length, I've concluded that you can't actually use fitbounds or any of the other methods on an area different than the full map. Panning as you showed works, though, and in general if you fit bounds, pan, then zoom out by one, things will show up pretty much as I need them to. So, I'll accept this answer on that basis. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is described here: [How to make fitBounds aware of custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152596/how-to-make-fitbounds-aware-of-custom-controls). Plus, you can use containsLocation to double check that either technique worked ([Google Maps fitBounds into specific area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977880/google-maps-fitbounds-into-specific-area))