# Google Maps fitBounds into specific area

Tags: google-maps, gis

I want to achieve the following: "Place an array of markers that may be distributed across a large range of lat, lng into a fitbounds method that places the fitbounds inside a custom rectangle."

The image below should clarify what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I have an array of markers that I want to make sure always fits within a small box on the right hand side of my page.

The white box contains some information pertaining to the markers, which will always be present, so I don't want any markers hidden behind the white box, and I'd love if I could define that they live within the black box. (Note the black box is just a visual reference for this question).

[image: google maps with bounds in a box]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the containsLocation to ensure a point is inside of a polygon.  See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly).

As you go through each coordinate pair in your array, verify the location is within the polygon area, then add to the map accordingly.  You can also set an attribute to those points to "define" what extent they are in.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.latLng(array[n]);
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, polygon)){  
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: latlng,
         map: map
     });
     marker.dataset.box = 'blackbox';
} else {  
     alert('Not inside black box');
}
```

If you're using HTML5, you can add a dataset attribute to markers that are within the polygon.

```
marker.dataset.box = 'blackbox';
```

If not, you can use setAttribute.

```
marker.setAttribute('data-box', 'blackbox');
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I didn't need to check that data existed in an area, rather I wanted to zoom in/out and move the map such that the all my markers were placed in a specific part of the screen.

Comment: I get that you are not wanting markers to be covered by the white box area.  From your original post, it sounds like you only want markers in the black box to appear, if so, my above answer will work.  If you want to fit all of your markers into the black box, you either need to change the coordinates of the markers to fit within the bounds of the box, or you need to put your entire map into the black box.  It's not very clear what you are wanting.

Comment: To clear up any confusion.

Markers can be distributed across a wide range of lat/lng (e.g. they may all be in Washington state, or the range may include some markers in Australia, Germany, USA).

I was hoping that I could move and/or resize (zoom in/out) the map (regardless of where the markers are) in such a way, that all the markers would appear to be grouped together in the black box area.